# Sturm-Liouville form of equation

Tags: boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

Recently I received a problem from two different people that want to convert an equation to a Sturm Liouville problem then solve it with boundary conditions. but I'm wondering how the problem could convert to it. there is a delta sign in it but what surprised me that I never see it in a Sturm-Liouville problem before. here is the question:

$\Delta{u}=xy^2+x^2y  \qquad \qquad \qquad -1<x<1 \quad\&\quad0<y<1 $

$ u(-1,y)=u(1,y)+y^2$

$u_x(-1,y)=u_x(1,y)+y$

$u_x(x,0)=x^2$

$u(x,1)+u_y(x,1)=x$

now my question is: is this problem is correct or just a miss typing(what do you think what was the original problem) if this problem is ok please give me a hint to solve it.
thank you all and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The *delta sign* is most likely the [Laplace Operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

Comment: @mrtaurho tnx alot. never see this notation before.

Comment: @mrtaurho can you give me a hint on how to solve it? (converting to Sturm-Liouville)

Comment: No problem for the reference; but I am sorry. Unfortunately I am not that into neither Sturm-Liouville Equations nor into PDEs. I am only used to the notation of the Laplace Operator (and the Nabla Operator respectively).